# Function returns 1 instead of result (PDO)

Tags: function, pdo

I have a function which is printed below. THis is meant to dynamicly draw user data from the database using PDO (that situation is clear and all works well). But, instead of returning the result (i e. an email for you("email)), it returns the number 1.

Here's my setup:

```
public function you($row) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE["SK"])) {
        $pw = $this->baseXencode($_SESSION["password"]);
        $usr = $this->baseXencode($_SESSION["username"]);
        $q = "SELECT $row FROM SN_users WHERE username=':USR' AND password=':PW'";
        $this->netCore->q($q);
        $this->netCore->bind(":PW", $pw);
        $this->netCore->bind(":USR", $usr);
        $result = $this->netCore->single();
        $result = $result[$row];
        return $result;
    } else {
        $q = "SELECT $row FROM SN_users WHERE username='Anonymous' AND password='Anonymous'";
        $this->netCore->q($q);
        $result = $this->netCore->single();
        $result = $result[$row];
        return $result;
    }
}
}

$this->netCore->q() = PDO query
$this->netCore->single() PDO fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

As for ->bind, self-explanatory.

Please help, will be very much appreciated.^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using parametrized queries, you don't put the parameters in quotes. That prevents the parameters from being substituted, since it's treated as a literal string. So it should be:

```
    $q = "SELECT $row FROM SN_users WHERE username=:USR AND password=:PW";
```

I'm surprised it's returning `1`. I'd expect your code to cause an error, because `single()` should be returning `false`, and `false[$row]` is not valid.

You should also check that a row was returned; if the username and password are not valid, you won't get an result. So it should be:

```
    $result = $this->netCore->single();
    if ($result) {
        return $result[$row];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

And the caller of `you()` needs to check the value as well.

Comment: This is the public function single() { $this->exe();return $this->state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } in my spiritNET class. Also, I've tried your suggestion, no luck... Maybe the single() function will help?

Comment: I followed a guide on the Culttt entitled "Rool out your own PDO class". The link for which is here: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

Comment: `single()` is exactly what I expected it to be. Are you sure you gave a valid username and password?

Comment: Possitive as I have just narrowed it down to a validated user stored in the php $_SESSION[]

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer. Did you figure out why it didn't work earlier?

Comment: Ahen I swap out $_SESSION["username"] for the baseXencoded Anonymous (no binding), it returns Anonymous' data (i e. name : John Davis).

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
     if(is_null($type)) {
      switch(true) {
       case is_int($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        break;
       case is_bool($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        break;
       case is_null($value):
        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        break;
       default:
        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
     }
     $this->state->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }